# I want the value of link_id in this.actionid and call the function in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a `js` code in my `.ts` file. It fetches the attribute from a span on click, i want to catch the attribute's value in a .ts variable and call a ts function

See my ngOnInit code, I just need the value of `link_id` in `this.actionid` and call a function `callpagedata()`

I have js code as follows in `home.ts`:

```
actionid;
 ngOnInit(){
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log("Inside Event Listener");
  event.preventDefault();
    var link_id = $(event.target).attr("action");
    console.log("Actionid is:: " + link_id);
});
}
```

I simply want the value of link_id in this.actionid and call the function callpagedata(). I tried like `this.actionid = linkId` but it doesn't allow `actionid` inside eventlistener and it doesn't allow `link_id` outside.

```
callpagedata(){

}
```

**home.html** code

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <span action="10004">Quick Task</span>
  <span action="10006">Quick Patrol</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference 'this' object inside the event handler. Here 'this' object represents your current event listener object. So try assigning your main function's 'this' object, like this_parent = this, and then access with this_parent.actionid :

```
 actionid;
    ngOnInit(){
        var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        let this_parent = this;
        mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            console.log("Inside Event Listener");
            event.preventDefault();
            var link_id = $(event.target).attr("action");
            console.log("Actionid is:: " + link_id);
            this_parent.actionid = link_id;
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use jQuery to do it. And, i also recommend you to use angular in that case.

But, keeping your code, you can do that

Typescript:

```
ngOnInit(){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      console.log("Inside Event Listener");
      event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target);
        var link_id = (<HTMLElement>event.target).getAttribute('action');
        // the cast is necessary because we're using typescript, so, we have to tell to the compiler, that the event.target is an HTMLElement.
        console.log("Actionid is:: " + link_id);
    });
}
```

I've test and this code works fine. But i recommend you to use `Angular Events`, so you can have something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <span (click)="myFunction(10004)">Quick Task</span>
  <span (click)="myFunction(10006)">Quick Patrol</span>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
myFunction(value: number): void {
    console.log('my value', value);
}
```

I hope it help you.